# What is the best method to list all the files of an extension in a directory?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, find, command

After some research, I ended up with few methods. The most logical one is,

```
muyustan@muyustan-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ find . -name "*.srt"
```

But the output of this command *also* includes the files on subdirectories of the working directory , **which I don't intend to do.**

```
./The.Walking.Dead.S10E11.Morning.Star.720p.AMZN.WEB-DL.DD+5.1.H.264.srt
./the.walking.dead.s10e12.web.h264-xlf.srt
./The.Walking.Dead.S10E11.1080p.WEB.H264-XLF.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x04] - The One with the Sharks.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x16] - The One with the Boob Job.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x17] - The One with the Memorial Service.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x03] - The One with the Pediatrician.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x02] - The One Where Emma Cries.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x21] - The One with the Fertility Test.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x01] - The One Where No One Proposes.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x18] - The One with the Lottery.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x12] - The One with Phoebe's Rats.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x11] - The One Where Rachel Goes Back to Work.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x15] - The One with the Mugging.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x09] - The One with Rachel's Phone Number.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x07] - The One with Ross's Inappropriate Song.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x05] - The One with Phoebe's Birthday Dinner.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x08] - The One with Rachel's Other Sister.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x14] - The One with the Blind Dates.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x13] - The One Where Monica Sings.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x19] - The One with Rachel's Dream.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x20] - The One with the Soap Opera Party.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x06] - The One with the Male Nanny.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x22] - The One With The Donor.srt
./fs9s/Friends - [9x10] - The One with Christmas in Tulsa.srt
muyustan@muyustan-ubuntu:~/Downloads$
```

So, I would be thankful if anyone supplies me with a neat method to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to list them and not [creating a script](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), `ls *.src` will do.